# How can I resolve this Craft migration error on running migrate

Tags: migration

I get
Invalid general config setting: SITE_URL
When running the final Craft4 migration CLI

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `siteUrl` setting has been [deprecated in Craft 3 and removed in Craft 4](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/upgrade.html#configuration). Furthermore, Craft 4 removed the ability to set custom config values in `general.php` (you can now set [custom settings in a `custom.php`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/#custom-settings)), so every setting that doesn't exist will result in errors. Remove that setting from your `config/general.php` or anywhere else the settings might be overwritten and the error should go away. If you have a `CRAFT_SITE_URL` environment variable, you need to remove that as well, since Craft 4 will [parse environment variables into settings directly](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/#config-files).

All of this is mentioned in the upgrade guide linked below – make sure to read that and follow all the steps when updating a site from Craft 3 to 4 (or between any other major versions).

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/#env